# C# Picturebox stretch memory issues

Tags: c#, picturebox

I know this question has been asked before, but my issue relates directly to using 'Stretch' (or anything other than 'Normal') with the picturebox, 'Normal' works perfectly.

I have a simple application that essentially takes a screenshot 60 times per second `_timer.Interval = (1.0/60.0) * 1000.0;` using timers.  Unfortunately, using 'stretch' causes more and more memory to be used, eventually crashing the application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsed);
        _timer.Interval = (1.0/60.0) * 1000.0;
    }

    private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnElapsed(object o, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height));

            using (Image prev = pbCapture.Image)
            {
                pbCapture.Image = bmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I dispose of both the graphics IDisposable and the previous image used by the picturebox. However, the memory still increases.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `bmp` disposed?

Comment: If I try and dispose bmp, causes an 'invalid parameter' exception on .CopyFromScreen.

Comment: The bitmap does need disposing - you could try getting another reference to the bitmap just before assigning to pbCapture.Image & then disposing. I see @PatrickArtner beat me to saying this.

Comment: The problem comes from setting the picturebox to anything other than 'Normal'.  Causes a large memory leak in 'Stretch' for example.  100ms seems fine, but using something like 16.6 (60fps), problems arise.

Comment: Use a lower interval, will cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

Creating large amounts of big bitmaps at such a high rate is generally a bad approach. I would suggest you to create a cache bitmap once to reduce the memory pressure. You can also use any GDI functions to directly copy the bitmap data.

The memory leak reason in your case is a multi-threading issue.
The default timer resolution on Windows is 15.6 ms. At the rate of 60 Hz (16.67 ms), there is a high probability of at least two events to get fired almost simultaneously.

It's obvious that in such case you'll get a race condition, so your bitmaps won't be disposed properly and will hang in memory (in the finalizer queue). And since you're heavily loading your CPU, the Garbage Collector cannot effectively get rid of the zombie objects.

To check that, just setup a simple `lock` section in your event handler so that only one thread can access the bitmap at a time. You'll notice that no memory leak will occur anymore.

You could of course change the timer resolution to e.g. 1 ms. But then you have to guarantee that your bitmap processing will be finished until the next event arrives. It's hard to do in the .NET world.

Another solution is to change the `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. The later will raise events on the GUI thread instead of the thread pool threads. But you have to keep in mind that all the processing will be done on the GUI thread making your user interface unresponsive.

Maybe the best solution is to implement some 'drop frame' behavior. If a frame arrives while the previous one is still being processed, then just drop the new frame. You can do this with e.g. a `Semaphore`.

Another solution, as suggested by @ BradleyUffner, is to make the timer non-repeatable and to enable the next event handler after a frame has been processed.

Comment: Another option is to not make the timer automatically repeat.  Set it to fire once, process the bitmap, and *then* update the timer to fire again.  That will stop them from overlapping, and will allow them to run at the max speed for the workload being processed.

Answer (score 2):

The Timer.Elapsed event runs on a threadpool thread.  That is a problem, neither the Image.Dispose() method nor the PictureBox.Image property are thread-safe.  Winforms has a heuristic to throw an InvalidOperationException when you get this wrong, but it is not capable of detecting this for either member.

The failure mode occurs when the Elapsed event handler calls Dispose() at the exact time that the UI thread is busy repainting the Image.  This appears to trigger undefined behavior in the Bitmap class, all I can see is that the Dispose() call just doesn't have any affect.  The GDI Object counter ticks up (visible in Task Manager) and correspondingly the memory usage increases.  Only very occasionally does it trigger a hard "Object in use elsewhere" exception.  An exception you cannot see easily because both PictureBox.OnPaint() and Timer.OnElapsed() have try/catch-em-all statements.

Changing the SizeMode property to Stretch only has a secondary affect, it causes the Paint event to take longer since it needs to work harder to resize the image.  So it increases the odds that the paint and the dispose occur at the same time.  The timer's Interval value has a very big effect as well, the lower it gets, the higher the odds that the paint isn't completed yet when the tp thread calls Dispose().

So as usual there is no Santa Clause, threading with thread-unsafe objects does always cause trouble.  You **must** do this correctly:

```
   this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        using (Image prev = pictureBox1.Image) {
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
    }));
```

With the additional requirement that you change the timer's AutoReset property to *false* so you can't cause another threading bug that occurs when the timer ticks before the previous Elapsed handler invocation is complete.  Albeit that you usually notice that earlier, all of those invokes will make the UI go catatonic when it can't keep up.  Something that can easily happen on a slow machine btw.  Only a synchronous timer, the one in the toolbox, can ensure that will never happen.  Which is the best advice.